# A clean way to "add a cooldown" to fullpage.js scrolling with anchor buttons (without removing the anchors)?

Tags: reactjs, fullpage.js

was wondering if anyone can give me advice on this matter about fullpage.js with react.

My problem is that spamming buttons between sections causes scrolling to become erratic and background images to flicker. setAllowScrolling(false, 'all') etc doesn't seem to work for scrolling via buttons (works normally via wheel). Also need those anchors on at all times because I use the active class they add to the components.

#### Steps to reproduce it

1. Added a navbar outside the wrapper since I want it to be fixed.
2. Added the menu functionality on my list with anchors etc.
3. If the user spams them, scrolling becomes erratic and I am at a loss as to how to set a cooldown for them, since the anchor buttons seem to be an internal plugin function.

[Chrome, Firefox, Windows 10, desktop.]

---

Here is a barebones codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/portfolio-3gb8z

In the NavList.js at the moment, I got both onClick functions and anchors. The cooldowns I have implemented in the first two buttons work for the onClick functions but not the anchor/menu functionality.

Keep in mind that if you disable the onClick, the anchors will work only when clicking the outer button because the icons/text on the buttons don't register the click. That's why I also put onClick functions in there in the first place.

The thing is I just want to find a way to apply the cooldown on the anchors too. Problem is reproduced by spamming buttons in succession or spamming them while the scroll happens (try the 2 first buttons).

PS: I could just get rid of the anchors and keep the buttons with the working cooldown but I need that active class.

**TLDR:** because I suck at explaining: say you trigger a

```
  window.fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false, "all");
  window.fullpage_api.setKeyboardScrolling(false, "all");
```

The anchors still work - that's the essence of my problem.

Comment: If you can add a reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen that'd be great. That way we will be able to see your problem  and see if we can provide a solution.

Comment: Got a codesandbox but don't worry project is barebones only 2 files involved App.js and Components/Navigation/NavList.js. I'll update the OP with more info.

Comment: What's the issue? How to reproduce it? where should I click?

Comment: The issue is that setAllowScrolling(false, "all") disables scrolling for onClick and mouse wheel events as intended, but doesn't seem to disable scrolling when clicking on listitems linked with anchors that move you to the respective section.

Comment: Try using `setLockAnchors`method: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setlockanchorsboolean

Comment: Mate, I just found the culprit. Sorry for wasting your time. I won't need a cooldown for anchor buttons after all. I had scrollbar={true}, and that apparently caused changing sections with the anchor buttons very fast, while the previous smooth scrolling was already happening, to become erratic (elements flickering etc).